# How to install windows 7/8.1 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot

i installed ubuntu 14.04 on my windows8.1. i tried to do a dual boot, but i accidentally click the wrong option and now, the windows8.1 gone and currently, ubuntu14.4 is my only OS. i do have the windows8.1 iso. so, how to install the windows8.1 again?

Comment: ***Unless you have already customised Ubuntu / applications, just start over.*** Somehow restore Windows 8.1 (replacing Ubuntu), then try again.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu, you have several types.
- install ubuntu with windows 8.1
- replace windows 8.1 with ubuntu
- ...

If you choice the replace intall type, you must install windows 8.1 again.
but, if you choice the first type(install with windows),
there are something wrong with Grub.

check this how-to documents.
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: how to install the windows8.1 again?